# How to avoid particular url to track and duplicacy by Google analytics?

Tags: web, google-analytics

I have a website developed in asp.net MVC4 with Google analytics code. We noticed three issues while analyzed GA reports:

1. It displays admin pages (like "/Areas/Register/Views/Merchandiser/Create.cshtml", for example) and shouldn't be in analytics report
2. It displays duplicated (like "/myurl" and "/myURL", for example) urls and shouldn't be duplicated
3. It displays error pages (like "/Errors?aspxerrorpath=/Admin/Conteudos", for example) and shouldn't be in analytics report.

For #2, I have gone through this [link](http://www.gapremium.com/2012/02/how-to-remove-duplicate-urls-in-google-analytics/#.VBHz53kcTIU) but I did not get the results even after 72hrs.

For #1 & #3 - can I use robots.txt ? - if yes, how can I use this for asp.net mvc4 website?

Is there any way to resolve above issues?

Any help in this regard will be highly obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that asp.net is allowing case-insensitive URLs while google analytics considers foo/bar and Foo/Bar to be different urls and is the correct behavior per the W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html .

Comment: @caskey- you are right, GA is case-sensitive, but is there any solution of my problem. It looks like a common issue :(

Comment: Sadly this has come up before, if you search on "asp.net case insensitive urls" you'll find people struggling to disable this 'feature'. The only workaround would be for you to make your website always redirect users to the 'canonical' version of the url.

Comment: Yeah! I got it, what did you say. But, what about #1 & #3 ?

Comment: Just don't include the analytics script/code on the pages you don't want them on?